# Is a Binary Search Tree inherited upward or inherited downward?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

And why? I tried googling but it wouldn't come up with any answers.

I know that if the two nodes of the root are binary search trees, then the top one is a binary search tree. But does this mean that it is inherited upward or inherited downward?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is like - insanity is hereditary, you get it from your kids.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Inheritance (assuming you're talking about the OOP concept), applies to *data types*.

Comment: What do you mean by up or down in this context?

Comment: trees with leaves at the top are equivalent to trees with leaves at the bottom under isomorphism.

Comment: Wow, that actually clears things up immensely. :)

Comment: @Oli by "inherited upward" I mean that whenever the left and right subtrees of the root satisfy the property, so does the tree itself.

Comment: If by your second paragraph you mean "If the two children of the root are binary search trees, then the root is a binary search tree", then that's *wrong*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were writing a function to check if a tree is a BST, then you would start at the top node, and recursively go down the child nodes checking if each one is a BST tree as well. On the other hand, you can also start at the bottom and work your way up inductively. Both solutions are ideal.

Comment: Actually, this wasn't the best answer, but I thought I'd just pick one to substitute for Romain Hippeau's answer as a comment to my question above.